# Create a wrapper for external module in typescript

Tags: excel, typescript, wrapper, exceljs

I haven't much exp in typescript and I stuck with this problem:

1. I have a stub for [ExcelScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.workbook?view=office-scripts) namespace, with stub classes, interfaces and methods.
2. Now I need to make this thing actually work on my local machine, so I decided to use the [ExcelJs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) library.
3. Difficulties:

- they have the same named methods
- ExcelScript has methods absent in the ExcelJs

Question: what is a good way to make my ExcelScript stub a wrapper for the ExcelJs?

ExcelScript stub:

```js
export namespace ExcelScript {
  export class Workbook {
    getWorksheet(indexOrName: string | number): Worksheet {

      const worksheet: Worksheet = new Worksheet;
      return worksheet;
    }

  }
  export enum RangeCopyType {
    values
  }

  export class Worksheet {
    getCell(x: number, y: number): Range {
      const range: Range = new Range;
      return range;
    }
    getRange(x: number | string, y?: string): Range {
      const range: Range = new Range;
      return range;
    }
    getTables(): Table[] {
      return [new Table];
    }

  }
  export class Range {

    setValue(value: string | number | boolean | Date): Range {
      const range: Range = new Range;
      return range;
    }
    copyFrom(rangge: Range, copyType: RangeCopyType): [][] {
      return [[]];
    }
    getText(): string {
      return '';
    }
    getTexts(): [][] {
      return [[]];
    }
    getValue(): string | number | boolean | Date {
      return '';
    }
    setNumberFormat(formatString: string) {

    }
    convertDataTypeToText() {

    }
  }
  export class Table {
    getRange(x?: string, y?: string): Range {
      const range: Range = new Range;
      return range;
    }
    getTexts(): [][] {
      return [[]];
    }
  }
}
```